# Xamarin: PresentModalView new View is not visible

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to navigate(presentmodalview) from one screen to another in Xamarin(MvvmCross framework_V2), navigation is happening(can see the navigation bar changing) but screen is not visible(previous screen is visible). What could be the possible reason for that. Any ideas?

Adding Code:
in MainMenu

```
 private void ActionFavouritePressed()  
 {
    ViewModel.ShowInfoCommand.Execute ();
 }
```

in MainMenuViewModal

```
    public MvxRelayCommand ShowInfoCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxRelayCommand(() =>
            {
                this.RequestNavigate<InfoViewModel>();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add your code...

Comment: Also are you wanting to navigate or show a modal view?

Comment: Thanks for your response, we are just presenting (using presentModalView method) a new screen( which is a inherited by UINavigationController), but new screen is not visible. Just the old one is visible.

Comment: Does your ViewController have any views in it? that might explain why you don't see anything but you do see the title change. If the background of your view is clear, it'll show through whatever is behind it.

Comment: There's probably some exception happening somewhere in your ViewModel or View construction code - too hard to debug from what you have here. Try adding trace, stepping through your code, looking at the debug output, etc.